# How to parse JSON file format?

Tags: php, json

Just wondering how to parse this kind of JSON structure:

```
{
    "vehicles": [
        {
            "key": "1",
            "plate": "BLANKET",
            "assignee_key": "",
            "assignee": {
                "key": "",
                "fname": "",
                "mname": "",
                "lname": ""
            },
            "year": "",
            "make": "",
            "model": ""
        },
        {
            "key": "2",
            "plate": "BLANKET1",
            "assignee_key": "",
            "assignee": {
                "key": "",
                "fname": "",
                "mname": "",
                "lname": ""
            },
            "year": "",
            "make": "",
            "model": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I use this kind of code to parse it but cant get the plate and other field.

```
$string = file_get_contents("sample.json");
$json = json_decode($string,true);
foreach($json as $res){
    echo $res['plate'].'<br/>';
}
```

I always getting this error "Notice: Undefined index: plate".

Comment: `foreach($json['vehicles'] as $res)` surely?

Comment: try  foreach($json['vehicles'] as $res){
    echo $res['plate'];
}

Comment: got it thanks guys. forgot about the vehicles from the json.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `vechicles` key

Your array have this child and all elements are put under it.

```
$string = file_get_contents("sample.json");
$json = json_decode($string,true);
foreach($json['vehicles'] as $res){
    echo $res['plate'];
}
```

**Output:**

```
BLANKET
BLANKET1
```